# Vote breakdown missing minus sign when >= 100 downvotes

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, vote-count

In the upvotes/downvotes breakdown you get by clicking on a post's votes, it appears the minus sign goes missing if there's at least three digits worth of downvotes. This can be seen in e.g. [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) which looks like this to me:

[image]

Many other questions with less than 100 downvotes show correctly.

It's not that the minus sign would be hidden, or wouldn't fit the horizontal space: there's plenty of space for the upvotes to fit (and there are cases with five digits of upvotes), and indeed Chrome's Inspect tool shows the generated element as:

```
<div class="fc-red-600">201</div>
```

In cases with less than three digits, the minus sign is there inside the `div`.
In the one case I found with that many downvotes, all four digits were shown, without the minus...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Vote split does not include leading sign when count exceeds 99](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45436/289905) on MSE.

Comment: @user4642212, right, so that one has a ten-year old accepted answer that refers to the numbers not fitting, when it's clear from the Q I linked and from e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git) that even five digits fit fine. Five digits _and_ a minus sign might be different though, but I expect posts that gathered 10000 downvotes wouldn't be visible anyway.

Comment: And yes, on a closer look, the plus sign also disappears at 100 upvotes, but in that case, meaning of the number is still the same.

Comment: this is such an old issue, I'd be shocked if there wasn;'t an MSO duplicate